# Webpack plugin showin an unknown property

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, npm-start

Following is my webpack config file and package.json. When I run `webpack -w` I am getting the following error (pasted in last). I think it has something to do with path string. Thank you in advance.

**webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const ImageminPlugin = require('imagemin-webpack-plugin').default;
const TerserJSPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const SVGSpritemapPlugin = require('svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin')
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");

const PATHS = {
  src: path.join(__dirname, './src'),
  dist: path.join(__dirname, './dist')
}

const PAGES_PUG = `${PATHS.src}/pug/`;
const PAGES = fs.readdirSync(PAGES_PUG).filter(filename => filename.endsWith('.pug'));

module.exports = {
  
  entry:  {
    app: [`${PATHS.src}/scripts/app.js`, `${PATHS.src}/scss/styles.scss`]
  },
  output:{
    path: `${PATHS.dist}`,
    filename: './scripts/[name].[hash].min.js'
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [new TerserJSPlugin({}), new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})],
    splitChunks: {
      cacheGroups: {
        vendor: {
          name: 'vendor',
          test: /node_modules/,
          chunks: "all",
          enforce: true,
          
        }
      }
    }
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  devServer: {
    overlay: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.pug$/,
        loader: 'pug-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {sourceMap: true}
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {sourceMap: true}
          }
        ],
        exclude: '/node_modules'
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {sourceMap: true}
          },
          {
            loader: "postcss-loader",
            options: {sourceMap: true}
          },
          {
            loader: "resolve-url-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {sourceMap: true}
          },
        ],
        exclude: '/node_modules'
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: '/node_modules'
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: ['babel-loader', 'ts-loader'],
        exclude: '/node_modules'
      },
      {
        test: /.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/,
        use: ['url-loader']
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    ...PAGES.map(page => new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: `${PAGES_PUG}/${page}`,
      filename: `./${page.replace(/\.pug/, '.html')}`
    })),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      template: `${PATHS.src}/styles/styles.scss`,
      filename: `styles/styles.[hash].min.css`
    }),
    new CopyPlugin({
      patterns: [
        { from: './src/assets/favicon', to: 'assets/favicon', noErrorOnMissing: true },
        { from: './src/assets/img', to: 'assets/img', noErrorOnMissing: true}
      ]
    }),
    new ImageminPlugin({
      disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production', // Disable during development
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i }),
    new SVGSpritemapPlugin('./src/assets/icons/icons-colored/**/*.svg', {
      output: {
        filename: 'assets/sprites/sprites-colored/sprites.svg',
        svg4everybody: true,
        svgo: {
          plugins: [
            { inlineStyles: { onlyMatchedOnce: false } },
            { minifyStyles: true }
          ]
        }
      },
      sprite: {
        prefix: false
      }
    }),
    new SVGSpritemapPlugin('./src/assets/icons/icons-solid/**/*.svg', {
      output: {
        filename: 'assets/sprites/sprites-solid/sprites.svg',
        svg4everybody: {
          polyfill: true
        },
        svgo: {
          plugins: [
            {removeAttrs: {attrs: '(stroke|fill|style)'}}
          ]
        }
      },
      sprite: {
        prefix: false
      }
    })
  ],
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "webpack-config",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.2",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "cheerio-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.2",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.3.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "cssnano": "^4.1.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "imagemin-webpack-plugin": "^2.4.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^1.3.1",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.4",
    "postcss": "^8.1.7",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.4",
    "pug": "^3.0.0",
    "pug-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "svg-spritemap-webpack-plugin": "^3.7.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.11",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "type-check": "tsc --noEmit",
    "type-check:watch": "npm run type-check -- --watch",
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "start": "webpack -w",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
```

**error**

```
webpack -w

[webpack-cli] ValidationError: Invalid options object. Mini CSS Extract Plugin has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'template'. These properties are valid:
   object { filename?, chunkFilename?, ignoreOrder?, insert?, attributes?, linkType? }
    at validate (D:\webdev\scripts\github\webpack-config-master\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\node_modules\schema-utils\dist\validate.js:104:11)        
    at new MiniCssExtractPlugin (D:\webdev\scripts\github\webpack-config-master\node_modules\mini-css-extract-plugin\dist\index.js:47:31)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\webdev\scripts\github\webpack-config-master\webpack.config.js:117:5)
    at Module._compile (D:\webdev\scripts\github\webpack-config-master\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:952:19)
    at require (D:\webdev\scripts\github\webpack-config-master\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at requireConfig (D:\webdev\scripts\github\webpack-config-master\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\groups\resolveConfig.js:73:18) {
  errors: [
    {
      keyword: 'additionalProperties',
      dataPath: '',
      schemaPath: '#/additionalProperties',
      params: [Object],
      message: 'should NOT have additional properties',
      schema: false,
      parentSchema: [Object],
      data: [Object]
    }
  ],
  schema: {
    type: 'object',
    additionalProperties: false,
    properties: {
      filename: [Object],
      chunkFilename: [Object],
      ignoreOrder: [Object],
      insert: [Object],
      attributes: [Object],
      linkType: [Object]
    }
  },
  headerName: 'Mini CSS Extract Plugin',
  baseDataPath: 'options',
  postFormatter: null
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! webpack-config@1.0.0 start: `webpack -w`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-config@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Answer (score 0):

MiniCssExtractPlugin hasn't `template` plugin option, you can't write the `template` option when you new a MiniCssExtractPlugin instance.

MiniCssExtractPlugin only has six plugin options: `filename`、`chunkFilename`、`ignoreOrder`、`insert`、`attributes` and `linkType`.